# Compare each line from two different files and print the lines that are different in C

Tags: c, io

Supposing that I have two files like this:

**file1.txt**

```
john
is
the new
guy
```

**file2.txt**

```
man
the old
is
rick
cat
dog
```

I'd like to compare first line from `file1` with all the lines from `file2` and verify if it exist. If not, go two the second line from `file1` and compare it with all the lines from `file2`.. and so on until `eof` is reached by `file1`.

The output that I expect is:

```
john
the new
guy
```

How I thought this should be done:

- read `file1` and `file2`
- create a function which returns the line number of each of them
- take the first line from `file1` and compare it to all the lines from `file2`
- do this until all the lines from `file1` are wasted

Now, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I don't get the result that I expect:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int countlines(char *filename)
{                                
    int ch = 0, lines = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return 0;

    do {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if (ch == '\n')
            lines++;
    } while (ch != EOF);

    if (ch != '\n' && lines != 0)
        lines++;
    fclose(fp);

    return lines;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *template_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE *data_file = fopen(argv[2], "r");

    char buffer_line_template_file[100];
    char buffer_line_data_file[100];


    if (argc != 3)
    {
        perror("You didn't insert all the arguments!\n\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (template_file == NULL || data_file == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file!\n\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < countlines(argv[1]); i++)
    {
        fgets(buffer_line_template_file, 100, template_file);

        for (int j = 0; j < countlines(argv[2]); j++)
        {
            fgets(buffer_line_data_file, 100, data_file);

            if (strcmp(buffer_line_template_file, buffer_line_data_file) != 0)
            {
                counter++;
                printf("%d", counter);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Could someone please point me into the right direction ? For testing purposes I created a counter at the end which was a part of a small debug. There should be the `print()` function

---

As per [@chux answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37668293/3316077) I got the following simplified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *template_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE *data_file = fopen(argv[2], "r");

    char buffer_line_template_file[100];
    char buffer_line_data_file[100];


    if (argc != 3)
    {
        perror("You didn't insert all the arguments!\n\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (template_file == NULL || data_file == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file!\n\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(fgets(buffer_line_template_file, 100, template_file))
    {
        buffer_line_template_file[strcspn(buffer_line_template_file, "\n")] = '\0';

        rewind(data_file);
        while (fgets(buffer_line_data_file, 100, data_file))
        {
            buffer_line_data_file[strcspn(buffer_line_data_file, "\n")] = '\0';

            if (strcmp(buffer_line_template_file, buffer_line_data_file) != 0)
            {
                printf("%s\n", buffer_line_template_file);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The above code is giving me the following output, which is not what is expected:

```
john
john
john
john
john
john
is
is
is
is
is
the new
the new
the new
the new
the new
the new
guy
guy
guy
guy
guy
guy
```

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: A function `char const * readline(FILE *);` could be helpful. Then, to keep this simple (you can improve upon it later), look how you can "reset" the read position of a FILE, i.e. how to get back to the beginning.

Comment: You description does not match your expectation...wait..are you a part of clients from hell? :P

Comment: @melpomene I get all the words from `file2` and the last one is being multiplied several times. Daniel, that's a nice advice, I'll try it. Sourav, nope, I'm just a poor alien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems with OP's code

1. Imprecise definition of line.
2. Excessive recalculation
3. Fuzzy determination of the number of lines in a file.

---

1. Unlike `string`, which has a precise definition in C, reading a *line* is not so well defined.  The primary specificity issue: does a line contain the trailing `'\n'`.  If the first answer is *Yes*, then does the last text in a file after a `'\n'` constitute a line?  (Excessively long lines are another issue, but let us not deal with that today.)

Thus possibly *some* lines end with `'\n`' and others do not, fooling `strcmp("dog", "dog\n")`.

The easiest solution is to read a *line* until either 1) a `'\n'` is encountered, 2) `EOF` occurs or 3) line buffer is full.  Then after getting a line, lop off the *potential* trailing `'\n'`.

Now all *lines* code subsequently works with have no `'\n'`.

```
fgets(buffer_line_template_file, 100, template_file);
buffer_line_template_file[strcspn(buffer_line_template_file, "\n")] = '\0';
```

2. OP's loop is incredible wasteful.  Consider a file with 1000 lines.  Code will loop, calling 1000 times `countlines()` (each `countlines()` call reads 1000 lines) times when one `countlines()` call would suffice.

   ```
   // for (int j = 0; j < countlines(argv[2]); j++)
   int j_limit = countlines(argv[2]);
   for (int j = 0; j < j_limit; j++)
   ```
3. There really is no need to count the line anyways, just continue until `EOF`  (`fgets()` returns `NULL`).  So no need to fix its fuzzy definition.  (fuzzy-ness concerns same issues as #1)

   ```
   int counter = 0;
   for (fgets(buffer_line_template_file, 100, template_file)) {
     buffer_line_template_file[strcspn(buffer_line_template_file, "\n")] = '\0';

     rewind(data_file);
     while ((fgets(buffer_line_data_file, 100, data_file)) {
       buffer_line_data_file[strcspn(buffer_line_data_file, "\n")] = '\0';

       if (strcmp(buffer_line_template_file, buffer_line_data_file) != 0) {
         counter++;
         printf("%d", counter);
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Other simplifications possible - for another day.

---

FWIW, following counts *lines* of text allowing the last line in the file to optionally end with a `'\n'`.

```
    unsigned long long FileLineCount(FILE *istream) {
      unsigned long long LineCount = 0;
      rewind(istream);
      int previous = '\n';
      int ch;

      while ((ch = fgetc(inf)) != EOF) { 
        if (previous == '\n') LineCount++;
        previous = ch;
      }
      return LineCount;
    }
```

Note that this function may get a different result that `fgets()` calls.  Consider a file of one *line* of 150 characters.  `fgets(..., 100,...)` will report 2 lines.  `FileLineCount()` reports 1.

[Edit] Updated code to conform to OP functionality.

```
    int found = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer_line_data_file, 100, data_file))
    {
        buffer_line_data_file[strcspn(buffer_line_data_file, "\n")] = '\0';

        if (strcmp(buffer_line_template_file, buffer_line_data_file) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) printf("%s\n", buffer_line_template_file);
```

Comment: ., won't the `fgets(buffer_line_data_file, 100, data_file)` throw an error ?

Comment: That line it's indeed throwing an error as it is in that `for` block. I think there should be `while` instead. More, @chux, thanks for all your explanations. They are awesome. How would you replace that `counter` in order to print out the different lines ? Right now, I tried to implement your algorithm and what I get is `john x6` `is x5` `the new x6` `guy x6`. Updated code in the question.

Comment: Why not `if (strcmp(buffer_line_template_file...) continue;`? followed by `printf("%s\n", buffer_line_template_file);`? Is `found` required?

Comment: @David C. Rankin  Yes `found` required should `data_file` contained multiple more than 1 match to prevent multiple prints.  Also efficient to not search rest of the file once a match was found.  Of course room for lots more efficiency improvements.

Answer (score 1):

This program prints the diff of two files `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    int ch1, ch2;
    char fname1[40], fname2[40];

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    char *line2 = NULL;
    size_t len2 = 0;
    ssize_t read2;

    fp1 = fopen("file1.txt", "r");
    fp2 = fopen("file2.txt", "r");

    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open %s for reading ", fname1);
        exit(1);
    } else if (fp2 == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open %s for reading ", fname2);
        exit(1);
    } else {
        while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp1)) != -1 && (read2 = getline(&line2, &len2, fp2)) != -1) {
            if (!strcmp(line, line2)) {
                printf("Retrieved diff on line %zu :\n", read);
                printf("%s", line);
            }
        }
        if (ch1 == ch2)
            printf("Files are identical \n");
        else if (ch1 != ch2)
            printf("Files are Not identical \n");

        fclose(fp1);
        fclose(fp2);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: I believe it should be `if (strcmp(line, line2))`. According to the docs:
This function return values that are as follows:
if Return value < 0 then it indicates str1 is less than str2.
if Return value > 0 then it indicates str2 is less than str1.
if Return value = 0 then it indicates str1 is equal to str2.

Comment: Just a nit, for cleanup, you should show `free (line1);` and `free (line2);` to make clear you are freeing memory allocated by `getline` and still in use at exit. (yes , `exit` frees it, but for those unfamiliar with `getline`, it is a good reminder.) Also, the Question was to compare each line in file1 against *ALL* lines in file2, if I read it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a very good answer (and always will from chux), but here is a slightly different approach to the problem. It uses automatic storage to reading file2 into an array of strings and then compares each line in file1 against every line in file2 to determine whether it is unique. You can easily convert the code to dynamically allocate memory, but for sake of complexity that was omitted:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXC = 256, MAXL = 512 };

void file1infile2 (FILE *fp2, FILE *fp1, size_t *n2, size_t *n1);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *fp1 = fopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "file1.txt", "r");
    FILE *fp2 = fopen (argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "file2.txt", "r");
    size_t n1 = 0, n2 = 0;

    if (!fp1 || !fp2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\nunique words in file1, not in file 2.\n\n");
    file1infile2 (fp2, fp1, &n2, &n1);
    printf ("\nanalyzed %zu lines in file1 against %zu lines in file2.\n\n",
            n1, n2);

    return 0;
}

void file1infile2 (FILE *fp2, FILE *fp1, size_t *n2, size_t *n1)
{
    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    char f2buf[MAXL][MAXC] = { "" };
    size_t i;
    *n1 = *n2 = 0;

    while (*n2 < MAXL && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp2)) {
        char *np = 0;
        if (!(np = strchr (buf, '\n'))) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: line exceeds MAXC chars.\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        *np = 0;
        strcpy (f2buf[(*n2)++], buf);
    }

    while (*n1 < MAXL && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp1)) {
        char *np = 0;
        if (!(np = strchr (buf, '\n'))) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: line exceeds MAXC chars.\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        *np = 0, (*n1)++;

        for (i = 0; i < *n2; i++)
            if (!(strcmp (f2buf[i], buf)))
                goto matched;

        printf ("  %s\n", buf);
        matched:;
    }
}
```

Look over the code and let me know if you have any questions.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/f1inf2 dat/f1 dat/f2

unique words in file1, not in file 2.

  john
  the new
  guy

analyzed 4 lines in file1 against 6 lines in file2.
```